# Mixing in Traits Example

Tags: scala, traits

Given the following general service:

```
scala> trait Service[A, B] { def login: Either[A, B] }
defined trait Service
```

There are two services that, although not shown, make use of `Service#login`.

```
scala> trait CreateService extends Service[String, Int] {
     |   def create = ???
     | }
defined trait CreateService

scala> trait DeleteService extends Service[Boolean, Int] {
     |   def delete = ???
     | }
defined trait DeleteService
```

Then, in our `MainApp`, e.g. definition of routes in a web service, we need both of these services:

```
scala> object MainApp extends CreateService with DeleteService {}
<console>:13: error: illegal inheritance;
 object MainApp inherits different type instances of trait Service:
Service[Boolean,Int] and Service[String,Int]
       object MainApp extends CreateService with DeleteService {}
              ^
```

However, the above compile-time error occurs.

What's the right way to mix in the functionality of `CreateService` and `DeleteService` to `MainApp`?

Comment: They both require `login` to have a different signature.. how do you expect it to work?

Comment: I'm thinking of either (1) add a `trait` for A and B that both `CreateService`'s and `DeleteService`'s parameters will inherit. (2) duplicate the `login` function in each method. I'm not sure if taking step 1 will lead to bleeding `create` and `delete` logic together in a confusing way.